# Importing code from a c# vs code to unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote this code and it should make my character move(in unity)

```
public class Playermovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float moveSpeed;

    private Vector3 input;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        input = new Vector3(input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), 0, input.GetAxis ("Vertical"));
        print (input)
    }
}
```

and when i try and pull it onto my character in unity it says that "The Script don't enherit a native class that can manage a script"

Comment: If the script that this code is in is not named **exactly** `Playermovement.cs`, this is why.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest doing is in unity at the bottom where it says assets. Right-click create new script and call it Playermovement all from within in unity. Then open that file and just copy the body of the old into the new and all the references should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Very much appreciated